# How to view a new table as a pop up preview with the selected rows from an existing table in material-ui table in react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a new table with the selected rows from an existing MUI table. I need a preview of the selected rows when I click on a submit button.[Need a pop-up preview table or a new tab].

```
var selectedList = {};
const options = {
  filterType: "checkbox",
  selectableRows: false,
  selectableRowsOnClick: true,
  onRowsSelect: (rowData, rowState) => {
  selectedList = rowState;
  console.log("ddd", selectedList);
  }
 };

export default class FaqsDataList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  slide: "slideopen",
  inputhandle: "input--filled",
  value: "",
  createbot: "",
  faqList: [],
  response: [],
  selectedList: []
};
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

 getMuiTheme = () =>
   createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiPrivateSwitchBase: {
      root: {
        display: "block"
      }
    },
    MUIDataTableToolbar: {
      root: {
        display: "none"
      }
    }
  }
});


  submitList = () => {
var finaldata = [];
const selected = selectedList.map(item => {
  finaldata.push(this.state.faqList[item.dataIndex]);
});

 };

  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">FAQ list</h5>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-3">
                <label className="text-primary" for="exampleInputFile">
                  Select PDF File
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  accept="application/pdf"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  className="form-control-file"
                  id="exampleInputFile"
                  aria-describedby="fileHelp"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                  Upload
                </button>
              </div>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                onClick={() => this.submitList()}
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div className="peers fxw-nw pos-r">
          <div className="" id="main-window-scroll">
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.getMuiTheme()}>
              <MUIDataTable
                title={"FAQs Data List"}
                data={this.state.faqList}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
                // onRowClick={this.handleRowSelection}
              />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    {/* <FaqsUrlDataList/> */}
  </div>
);
}
}
```

this is my code, my selected rows are being stores in the var finaldata.
i need a preview table of the selected rows either in pop-up or a new tab.